# How to use MongoDb specific operator $size to find array size greater than, less than, between and not equal to a value in Laravel / jenssegers?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

I am working on a `Laravel dynamic where` clause eloquent model. I want to find the collection with the size of an array field having size values greater than, less than, between and not equal to.

I am using `jenssegers` and in the `jenssegers` documentation, the code to find documents with array size to a specific value is given, but I need to use it to `find` `<,>,!=` and `between`.

```
User::where('tags', 'size', 3)->get();
```

I can't use aggregate and $where since I am using a dynamic where clause to find the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the issue myself. The answer is:

**`$query->whereRaw(['$where' => 'this.tags.length > 1'])`**